# анимация div по клику

Tags: html, css, анимация

Использую `css` анимацию отсюда https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/.
Реализация такая, что просто дописывается к классу выбраная анимация. Например есть `div`:

```
<div class="containerTop"></div>
```

С анимацией он выглядит так:

```
<div class="containerTop animated bounce"></div>
```

При загрузке страницы все работает, но как сделать анимацию по клику? 
Алерты работают:

```
<div class="containerTop" onclick='alert("youClickedMe!");'></div>
```

Но когда я хочу добавить анимацию, то -нет.:

```
<div class="containerTop" onclick='animated bounce'></div>
```

JavaScript тоже не помог, значит делаю что-то не так.

Как это правильно реализовать?

Comment: `<div class="containerTop" onclick='animated bounce'></div>` - здесь ошибка, Вам нужно завести функцию, которая будет накладывать класс "`animated bounce`" по клику.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример запуска анимации по клику:

```js
// сама функция, которая накладывает класс
function startAnimation(e) {
  $("#containerTop").addClass("animated bounce");
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/daneden/animate.css/master/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="containerTop" class="container"></div>

<!-- Вешаем функцию startAnimation на клик кнопки -->
<button id="animate" onclick="startAnimation()">Animate!</button>
```